# Stored Procedure for inserting/updating two tables having a foreign key relation

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to database using mysql. I have two tables state and country where countryid is the foreign key in state table. I have a scenario where state can be added and while adding suppose the country turns out to be a new one then an insert has to be done on country table. My problem is I am going through various docs and I found rather than writing every query from java end its always consider better to organize everything into stored procedures and so I have started doing it.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`pratyush`@`%` PROCEDURE `ADD_STATE`(in statename varchar(45), in countryname varchar(45))
BEGIN
declare countryIdd varchar(45);
if (!checkNull(statename) AND !checkNull(countryname)) then
    if exists (select country_id from ems.country where country_name = countryname) then
        if not exists (select state_id from ems.state where state_name = statename) then
            select country_id into countryidd from ems.country where country_name = countryname;
            insert into ems.state(state_name, country_id) values(statename, countryidd);
        end if;
    end if;
end if;
END
```

Please let me know if I am going somewhere wrong.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`pratyush`@`%` PROCEDURE `ADD_STATE`(in statename varchar(45), in countryname varchar(45))
    BEGIN
    declare countryIdd varchar(45);
    if (!checkNull(statename) AND !checkNull(countryname)) then
        if exists (select country_id from ems.country where country_name = countryname) then
            if not exists (select state_id from ems.state where state_name = statename) then
                select country_id into countryidd from ems.country where country_name = countryname;
                insert into ems.state(state_name, country_id) values(statename, countryidd);
            end if;
        end if;
        if not exists (select countryid from country where countryname = @countryname) then
             if not exists (select stateid from state where statename = statename) then
                insert into ems.country(country_id,country_name) values(countryidd, countryname);
                select country_id into countryidd from ems.country where country_name = countryname;
                insert into ems.state(state_name, country_id) values(statename, countryidd);
             end if;
         end if;
    end if;
    END
```

Done certain changes to your code. I think you have to add another condition for checking whether the country exists and if not to insert into that table. Only thing you have to do is add a method to find the next country id to be inserted and store it in countryid. If the countryid field is int and auto incremental no need to find the id just insert the countryname it will automatically incremented to the next value. Sorry in advance if the answer is not useful and wrong